# MySql Workbench on Ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, mysql, software-installation, mysql-workbench

Hi I just installed the newest version of **Ubuntu, 14**, and now I need to install MySql Workbench.

I download the .deb package from mysql site but when I try to install it I obtain this error:

```
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-workbench-community-6.1.4-1ubu1310-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-workbench-community (6.1.4-1ubu1310) ...
dpkg:dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-workbench-community:
 mysql-workbench-community depends to mysql-client; however:
  The mysql-client package didn't install.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-workbench-community (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-workbench-community
```

I try to run `sudo apt-get -f install` and `sudo apt-get update`, I try to install manually dependecies but didn't work.

Can you help me?

Thank you

**EDIT**:

```
I ran: `dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql`
```

and I get this:

```
libdbd-mysql-perl               install
libmysqlclient18:amd64              install
mysql-client-5.6                install
mysql-client-core-5.6               install
mysql-common                    install
mysql-common-5.6                install
mysql-server-5.6                install
mysql-server-core-5.6               install
mysql-workbench-community           deinstall
```

Comment: You have to install mysql-client before. `sudo apt-get install mysql-client`

Comment: Yes I installed it before

Comment: But your error log says `The mysql-client package didn't install.` Make sure this package installed successfully.

Comment: I run this now: sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.6 but I obtain: mysql-client-5.6 is already the newest version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved in this way:

1) unistall mysql-server

2) delete all configuration about mysql-workbench

3) instead of use .tar.gz on mysql site, I install all by Software Center.

Now it works..

Comment: besides /usr/share/mysql-workbench, where else could I find config files? Still unable to install workbench with mysql 5.6 installed.

Comment: Run a command like: sudo find / -name mysql-workbench